# Are ENV Variables also passed as a part of HTTP request?

Tags: django, http, https, request

I was experimenting with Django middlewares. And I happened to randomly print out request.META, I saw that my Environment variables are also passed on to the django server.
[image]

My middleware.py

```
class AnalyticsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        for key in request.META:
            print(key, ":          ", request.META[key])
        return None
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: It seems `DEBUG` mode is activated. You can easily set it `False` in your `settings.py` file to deactivate debug mode.

Comment: Yes, debug mode is on. Is this expected behaviour for debug mode?

Comment: Yes, it is Django's default behavior of printing the error with environmental information for "debugging". It's useful for development, but it's strictly recommended to deactivate  Debug Mode in production environment.